# Failure with running TorqueBox on Ubuntu Quantal

Tags: ruby, jruby, torquebox

I'm trying to set up TorqueBox inside Vagrant on Ubuntu Quantal. I've deployed my app into TorqueBox, but when I try to run bin/standalone.sh, it hangs for a long time after "Setting up Bundler" and then simply says "Killed".

I'm at a complete loss as to how to debug this.

I followed this guide for the installation of TorqueBox: http://torquebox.org/documentation/2.3.0/production-setup.html

Here's the full log: https://gist.github.com/elabs-dev/5411966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a dump file in $TORQUEBOX_HOME/jboss/standalone/bin ?  If so, it could indicate that the JVM is crashing.

Otherwise, it could be that there is insufficient memory available to deploy whatever you're deploying - how large is your app?

Comment: The problem was indeed a lack of memory. I was running TorqueBox in a Vagrant VM and it seems that the reason the process was eventually killed was because it ate up all available memory. The reason why Bundler was so slow was that apparently Vagrant has performance problems on OS X with IO heavy operations.

Comment: Pretty much a carbon copy of what we see in our local TorqueBox + vagrant dev environment.  ON the plus side, TB is blisteringly fast on our linux servers.